# android opengl es2 rendering with fbo got balck screnn

Tags: java-native-interface, opengl-es-2.0

I try to make rendring android ndk opengl es2 with fbo. But got balck screen.
The following is the code.

init fbo

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &FBO);
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &RBO);
glGenTextures(1, &FTextureID);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FBO);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, RBO);

glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGB, m_width, m_height);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, RBO);


glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, FTextureID);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr);
glGenerateMipmap(FTextureID);

glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, FTextureID, 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    std::cout << "ERROR::POSTPROCESSOR: Failed to initialize FBO" << std::endl;

glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

init_render_data();

m_post_processor_shader.set_int("scene", 0, GL_TRUE);
```

init_render_data

```
    GLuint VBO;
GLfloat vertices[] = {
    // Pos        // Tex
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
     1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
     1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
     1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f
};

m_vertex_handle = glGetAttribLocation(m_post_processor_shader.get_id(), "vertex");
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "[Breakout][post_processor]", "glGetAttribLocation(\"vertex\") = %d\n",
                    m_vertex_handle);

glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


glEnableVertexAttribArray(m_vertex_handle);
glVertexAttribPointer(m_vertex_handle, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

class shader. set_int and use function

```
shader& shader::use()
{
    glUseProgram(m_id);
    return *this;
}

void shader::set_int(const GLchar* name, GLuint value, GLboolean use_shader)
{
    if(use_shader)
        use();

    glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(m_id, name), value);
}
```

shader

vertex

```
attribute vec4 vertex;

varying vec2 TexCoords;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(vertex.xy, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    TexCoords = vertex.zw;
}
```

fragment

```
precision mediump float;

varying vec2 TexCoords;
uniform sampler2D scene;

void main()
{ 
     gl_FragColor = texture2D(scene, TexCoords);
}
```

render

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FBO);
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

//render scene

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

//render texture from fbo
m_post_processor_shader.use();

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, FTextureID);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_VBO);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(m_vertex_handle);
glVertexAttribPointer(m_vertex_handle, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

Shader compile and link correct. fbo create correct

`glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER)` return `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE`.

Scene draw correct(without fbo). With fbo black screen.
May I ask what problems?

Comment: Why do you attach first a render buffer object and then a texture object to `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` of the frame buffer? The render buffer is completely useless, at the end the texture object is attached and the render buffer object is nowhere.

Comment: I render texture to the default framebuffer. It is in render functoin.

Comment: And after this in my code next

m_post_processor_shader.use();
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, FTextureID);

Answer (score 0):

I found mistake. in init_render_data variable name for Vertex buffer Object is VBO

```
GLuint VBO; 
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
```

in render function I use variable m_VBO

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_VBO);
```

and this whole mistake